# Delegated event and $(this).val()

Tags: jquery, console, html

I currently have the following code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".firstClass, .secondClass", function() {
     if ($(this).prop("class") == "firstClass") {
         //Something
     } else if ($(this).prop("class") == "secondClass") {
         console.log($(this).prop("class"));
         var variable = $(this).val();
         console.log(variable);
     }
});
```

The first `console.log()` returns what I would expect: `secondClass` however the second returns `null`. I imagine this is something to do with the delegated listener event, however what I can't understand is why `$(this)` is referenced correctly in the first instance, but not in the second.

I would expect a successful return in both cases, however that is clearly not the case. Why?

HTML is as follows:

```
<section>
    <h3>Heading</h3>
    <div>
        <div>
            <!-- .firstClass elements are dynamically created here within dynamically created div -->
            <div>
                <span class="firstClass">Some value</span>
                <span class="firstClass">Another value</span>
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <section>
        <h4>Heading</h4>
        <div>
            <!-- .secondClass elements are dynamically created here -->
            <span class="secondClass">Some value</span>
            <span class="secondClass">Another value</span>
            ...
        </div>
    </section>
</section>
```

Comment: Does your element have a value ?

Comment: @dystroy It's dynamically created, if that makes a difference? But I would have thought the delegated listener would have taken care of that if that was the problem.

Comment: @TusharGupta HTML added.

Comment: @dystroy In console, if I run a query on the element (`console.log($(this))`) it returns to me `<span class="secondClass">Value</span>` but if I run a query for the value as above (`console.log($(this).val())`) of that `span` I get `""` returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you try to get isn't a "value" as a `span` has no value (inputs have a value) it's the HTML content of the span.

Use

```
var variable = $(this).html();
console.log(variable);
```

or

```
var variable = $(this).text();
console.log(variable);
```

Comment: What an idiot... I've blinded myself to the simplicity of what is wrong here. Thanks a million.